Polygons are broken in generated MBTiles with Tippecanoe
I'm generating MBTiles with Tippecanoe, using such command
tippecanoe -Z11 -z16 -pc --no-line-simplification --extra-detail=12 --no-simplification-of-shared-nodes --drop-densest-as-needed --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping -P -o mbtiles/us_tx_06-05.mbtiles -l us_tx_06-05 --force --temporary-directory=/mnt/disk/decoded/mbtiles tx_*.json

but I have broken polygons on zoom levels higher than 16.
There is a red line on the screen where there must be a polygon border. Arrows point to parts of broken polygon border.

